# onColumnVisible property in AGGRid not making checkboxes in column panel checked or unchecked

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using AGGRID in react, my requirement is persist the selections on refresh.

- My AGGRID code is as below

---

```
<AgGridReact
  {...{
    rowData: plans,
    columnDefs,
    defaultColDef,
  }}
  ref={gridRef}
  rowSelection={'multiple'}
  key={isRTL ? '0' : '1'}
  enableRtl={isRTL}
  sideBar={sideBar}
  onColumnVisible={(event: any) => {
    const columnModel = gridRef.current?.columnApi.getColumnState();
    dispatch(setColumnModel(columnModel)); //saving the column state in redux store
  }} 
 />
```

- My issue is after using **dispatch(setColumnModel(columnModel)); //saving the column state in redux store** the column panel column checkboxes are unchecking or not checking up.

Can someone suggest on this issue

Comment: check this article 
https://blog.ag-grid.com/persisting-ag-grid-state-with-react-redux/

Comment: Hi Mina Fawzy, Thanks for sharing this article, but i  have already seen this. instead of this : this.debounceSaveGridColumnState(this.props.id, columnState);, i have used dispatch menthod. But later for fixing this i am calling an API passing the column filter info and setting it has resolved the issue.